# Error *** has no member named ***

Tags: c, tcp, structure

I don't know what i'm doing wrong ..

Do you have any ideas what i'm doing wrong? Structure was declared in header file sender.h - code below

After trying to compile this program I got this error:

```
Sender/Sender.c: In function 'SenderCreate':
Sender/Sender.c:50: error: 'Sender' has no member named 'sim_buf'
Sender/Sender.c:51: error: 'Sender' has no member named 'sim_buf_length'
Sender/Sender.c: In function 'SenderExecuteTask':
Sender/Sender.c:75: error: 'sim_buf_length' undeclared (first use in this function)
Sender/Sender.c:75: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
Sender/Sender.c:75: error: for each function it appears in.)
Sender/Sender.c:77: error: 'sim_buf' undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [Sender.o] Error 1
```

Code of program below:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // calloc, free
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Sender.h"
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include "../../rdo_module/readout_dev.h"

struct Sender_s {
    ET4DataSource *data_source;
    unsigned int num_of_images;
    unsigned int num_of_el;
    ConditionWait *condition_wait;
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr *PC;
    char *sim_buf;
    char *sim_buf_length;
};

void SenderSetNumOfEl(Sender *self, unsigned int num_of_el) {
    self->num_of_el = num_of_el;
}

Sender *
SenderCreate(ET4DataSource *data_source,
             unsigned int num_of_images,
             unsigned int num_of_el,
             ConditionWait *condition_wait,
             int sock,
             struct sockaddr *PC,
         char *sim_buf,                 // here I get some problems
         int *sim_buf_length)           // and here
{
    #ifdef DEBUG
        printf("Sender.c SenderCreate line 25: Sender *self = calloc(1, sizeof(Sender));\n");
    #endif

    Sender *self = calloc(1, sizeof(Sender));

    #ifdef DEBUG
        printf("Sender.c SenderCreate line 25: success\n");
    #endif

    self->data_source = data_source;
    self->num_of_images = num_of_images;
    self->num_of_el = num_of_el;
    self->condition_wait = condition_wait;
    self->sock = sock;
    self->PC = PC;
    self->sim_buf = sim_buf;
    self->sim_buf_length = sim_buf_length;

    return self;
}

void
SenderDestroy(Sender *self)
{
    free(self);
}

void *
SenderExecuteTask(void *self_)
{
    Sender *self = self_;
    ET4Buffer *buf = NULL;
    int n = 0;
    int c_len = sizeof(*(self->PC));

    while(1) {
            if(*sim_buf_length) {

                n=sendto(self->sock, sim_buf, *sim_buf_length, 0, self->PC, c_len);

                if(n < 0) {
                    perror("error in sendto()");
                    return NULL;
                }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Code of sender.h below:

```
#ifndef __SENDER_H__
#define __SENDER_H__

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include "../Utils/ConditionWait.h"
#include "../DataSource/ET4DataSource.h"

typedef struct Sender_s Sender;

Sender *
SenderCreate(ET4DataSource *data_source,
             unsigned int num_of_images,
             unsigned int num_of_el,
             ConditionWait *condition_wait,
             int sock,
             struct sockaddr *PC,
         char *sim_buf,
         int *sim_buf_length);

void
SenderDestroy(Sender*self);

void *
SenderExecuteTask(void *self_);

void SenderSetNumOfEl(Sender *self, unsigned int num_of_el);

#endif /*__SENDER_MAKER_H__*/
```

Comment: Probably you've forgot to save your file..

Comment: `#include "Sender.h"` (Capital S) and `Code of sender.h below:`  (Lower S).  Is that intended?  File `Sender.h` not posted, yet.

Comment: I've made a mistake in post. Of course name of file is ok - Sender.h

Comment: How can you make a mistake in the post if you copy/paste all your data - please see the comment from `Eugene Sh.`

Comment: I make a mistake in writing name of file. I know that i copy/paste all my data, but I want to show you whole file, cause I really don't know where I can make a mistake ..

Comment: line 50 of that code is `self->sock = sock;` which is not related to the error posted. Could you at least comment in the code which lines are causing the errors?

Comment: Kevin, i've made comments. It's true that I've send error before some changes in my code which change numbers of lines a bit.

Comment: There must be other errors before these! What are they? Post the WHOLE error message

Comment: In SenderExecuteTask you have `if(*sim_buf_length)` but sim_buf_length is never defined anywhere in that method.

Comment: It's whole error message.

Comment: FredK, if I change it to sim_buf_length_flag i'm getting same error .. I'm trying to do that but nothing happen.

Comment: Check your header files to make sure they compile cleanly

Comment: @FredK That's not a _method_ and C does not support _methods_ anyway.

Comment: Of the errors you report, I can reproduce only the one at line 77, relating to `sim_buf` being undefined.  Which it is -- maybe you meant `self->sim_buf`?  On the other hand, I get an error at line 51 different from the one you report, complaining "‘Sender’ has no member named ‘sim_buf_length’".  That actually corresponds to the code you presented, unlike the first two error messages you reported.

Answer (score 1):

The error messages and the source in the question don't match!

---

When I take the source given, the compiler tells, what is wrong.

- There is no member `sim_buf_length`, (note it does *not* complain about `sim_buf_length_flag`)
- I *don't* get the error message "error: ‘Sender’ has no member named ‘sim_buf’", because the member is clearly present
- Furthermore the types `char*` (Sender_s member) and `int*` (SenderCreate argument) don't match

---

The error messages for function `SenderExecuteTask` are clear, there are no variables declared `sim_buf` or `sim_buf_length(_flag)`. Probably the function signature should have been

```
void *SenderExecuteTask(Sender *self);
```

and then in the definition `self->sim_buf` and `self->sim_buf_length(_flag)` used respectively.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've correct errors and code. Still can't repair error from line 50 and 51 ..

Comment: Are those errors on the lines you marked in the file (with `here I got some problems` etc)? Because those are not related at all to the error you claim to have. If anything the errors would be on the line `self->sim_buf = sim_buf;` and the next line but I cannot reproduce that.

Comment: Even with the fixed source, it doesn't change much. Now the error message about missing member sim_buf_length is gone, but you still have the type mismatch between `int*` and `char*`.